# map, reduce with `|>` in julia

Tags: julia

In R, with `dyplr` you have the `%>%` operator which allows you to pipe the output of a function to a new function, removing the need to store intermediate values. In julia you can achieve something very similar by using the `|>` operator.

#### Example usage

```
2 |> log |> sqrt
```

To me this reads a lot nicer than `sqrt(log(2))`. Especially when the chain becomes very long. I would like to use this syntax but also for `map`,`reduce`-type functions in Julia.

#### Setup

```
from = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
to   = "cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab"
trans = "g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb <>"
d = Dict(from[i] => to[i] for i = 1:26)
d[' '] = ' '
```

#### What works

```
map(x -> d[x], filter(x -> isalpha(x) || isspace(x), trans))
```

This works, but it doesn't read as well as I would like it to. An alternative would be to store intermediate results into variables, but this also seems verbose:

```
res1 = filter(x -> isalpha(x) || isspace(x), trans)
map(x -> d[x], res1)
```

#### What I would prefer

The R syntax would be something similar to this:

```
trans |> 
  filter(x -> isalpha(x) || isspace(x)) |> 
  map(x -> d[x])
```

This will not work because in Julia the mapping/filter function goes before the iterable. R would solve this by giving you an infix `.` that you can use, in which case the syntax would look a bit more like:

```
trans |> 
  filter(x -> isalpha(x) || isspace(x), .) |> 
  map(x -> d[x], .)
```

Is something like this possible in Julia? The `|>` operator has the potential to clean up long chains of code into neat pipes of operations. A perhaps more Julia-thonic way of a approaching the problem would also be considered an answer to this question.

Comment: I've found chaining and pipes very convenient for data analysis.  Saves us from all the going-to-the-beginning-of-the-line and adding another function, and then going-to-the-end-of-the-line to add the right number of close parentheses, etc.

Comment: @rickhg12hs agreed. The flipside of course is that, same as if you've got a line with multiply-nested function calls, if you're relying on multiple chaining / redirections instead, particularly involving bespoke anonymous functions created for the sole purpose of achieving the redirection, chances are you could be writing code in discrete steps which would be a lot clearer to read (not to mention, amenable to proper commenting). But I agree, between nesting and chaining, chaining is much more pleasant visually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use the `@as` macro from the [Lazy](https://github.com/one-more-minute/Lazy.jl) package to get a little closer to your preferred form:

```
julia> using Lazy

julia> @as _ trans begin
         filter(x -> isalpha(x) || isspace(x), _)
         map(x -> d[x], _)
       end
"i hope you didnt translate it by hand "
```

Comment: Or even, `@>> trans filter(x -> isalpha(x) || isspace(x)) map(x -> d[x])` for this case.

Answer (score 14):

Not exactly sure what you're looking for, but:

**SPOILER ALERT**  8-)

```
julia> trans |> 
         t -> filter(x -> isletter(x) || isspace(x), t) |> 
         f -> map(x -> d[x],f)
"i hope you didnt translate it by hand "
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the duplication of defining variables in "the thing piped to"? Something like `trans |> filter(isdigit) |> map(x -> d[x])`? When I try I get "no method matching" errors.

Comment: @scubbo I haven't used Julia in quite some time.  I no longer feel qualified to respond - it might be better to ask a new question.

Answer (score 4):

You can you the [Pipe.jl](https://github.com/oxinabox/Pipe.jl) package to do it like this:

```
@pipe trans |> filter(x -> isalpha(x) || isspace(x), _) |> map(x -> d[x], _)
```

Or

```
@pipe ( trans 
     |> filter(x -> isalpha(x) || isspace(x), _) 
     |> map(x -> d[x], _)
)
```

The brackets around the arguments to the macro are needed if it goes onto multiple lines.

NB: I am the creator and maintainer of Pipe.jl

Comment: This is the second time I see someone create a julia package to overcome a problem with either the language or another package. The other one wrote ``TimeZonedDateTime`` stuff instead of fixing std::DateTime, and here, you created a macro to overcome the fact, that map is not working with chaining out of the box, possibly because of currying not working as expected. I start to see a pattern... a bad one.

Comment: That to me sounds like a feature, not a problem.

Comment: And that exactly is the problem. People see more glory in doing something new than fixing something old. This will lead to a myriad of packages which could have been avoided. And less, often is more.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different than the others, but I like

```
using Lazy

from = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
to   = "cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab"
trans = "g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb <>"

dd = Dict(zip(from, to))
@>> trans map(t -> isletter(t) ? dd[t] : t)
```

which yields

```
"i hope you didnt translate it by hand <>"
```